# Convert String to java.util.TimeZone

Tags: java

Currently, I am getting TimeZone in String. How can I convert it back to TimeZone ??

```
String timeZone = "Europe/Berlin"
```

How can I cast this to `java.util.TimeZone`

Answer (score 2):

By using the [`getTimeZone` static method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getTimeZone(java.lang.String)):

```
java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin")
```

Comment: but beware, as `TimeZone` is a legacy class. Use `ZoneId` instead in modern code.

Comment: @Hulk, absolutely true.